# MATLAB: convert vector into multidimensional array

Tags: matlab

A matrix of size (3,3,3,3,3) can easily be converted into a vector of size (3^5,1). Matlab help also states the formula for the conversion of an array of any dimension into a vector:

**In general, the offset formula for an array with dimensions [d1 d2 d3 ... dn] using any subscripts (s1 s2 s3 ... sn) is
(sn-1)(dn-1)(dn-2)...(d1)+(sn-1-1)(dn-2)...(d1)+...+(s2-1)(d1)+s1**

However, I am after the opposite, that is, I have a vector of length 3^5,1 and I want to populate the matrix of size (3,3,3,3,3). I try to do that in a recursive loop, but struggle to get it working properly. Has anyone had to solve this before and if so, where can I find an example (undoubtedly it is somewhere on the net).
Note that I am not after just reshaping the vector into the (3,3,3,3,3) matrix, but that I would like to know an equation that tells me where the i-th element of the vector ends up in the (a,b,c,d,e) location of the matrix.

Regards

Comment: What's wrong with using `reshape`?

Comment: `reshape(V,3,3,3,3,3)` maybe?

Comment: And just to clarify, I can use reshape to change the vector into the (3,3,3,3,3) matrix of course, but I want to know where the i-th value of the vector ends up in the (3,3,3,3,3) matrix. There has to be an equation/formula for that.

Comment: @FrankDrost `ind2sub([3 3 3 3 3], ind)`

Comment: or just `M(ind)`... you can still use linear indexing in the multidimensional matrix.

Comment: Thanks Beaker. I had used in2sub too, but that will give me the rows and column indices. What i am after is just the column number when row==1, i.e. a vector. Can you maybe somehow force ind2sub to a matrix of size (243,1)?

Comment: `sub2ind` would be the opposite of `ind2sub`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that might work. Although after a quick check the indices in ind2sub seem to go in the opposite direction as the size of the matrix, but I can work around that I think. Thanks for finding the obvious. I had used ind2sub and never clicked on in using sub2ind.

Comment: Use `Result = reshape(Vector, 3,3,3,3,3)`